# pip install logging: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

Tags: python

I've been googled on github and stackoverflow, but still got the error on my vm.

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-6u435q4r/logging/
```

I already tried:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

or

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

But still not working.

Comment: What is your python and pip version?

Comment: @GaneshK python 3.6 and pip 18.1

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing the same issue.

File "/private/var/pip-install-3xwk6dg3/logging/logging/**init**.py", line 618
        raise NotImplementedError, 'emit must be implemented '\
                                 ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

```
----------------------------------------
```

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/pl/jclz_xp15bl7t3y6ykhb4c_h0000gp/T/pip-install-3xwk6dg3/logging/